# Understanding testing process, such as BDD, through examples

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There is debate whether a question such as the following should be allowed on this forum: [Outside or within remit - should a BDD scenario be created for this user request](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12767/outside-or-within-remit-should-a-bdd-scenario-be-created-for-this-user-request)

A key reason why it should be allowed is:

- This question is about testing, because "deciding whether a requirement derives from a mission statement (a.k.a story or epic)" is in fact a core part of BDD, and BDD is testing. The disagreement probably arises from an overly narrow definition of testing, which is and should be seen as more than the technicalities of unit testing and such.

There are more (independent) key reasons for not just allowing but embracing such topics, but the above should be sufficient in my mind, so I will not go into the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see it both ways after reading over the linked question.  [Behavior Driven Development](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/bdd.html) builds a lot on TDD so I think it's a decent fit for it to be discussed on SQA though care should be taken to ensure that the questions are still on topic as requirements gathering isn't part of QA.

Ray, in regards to your linked question, I don't think it's appropriate.  You're asking us to determine if a particular feature matches the mission statement of a product.  If you asked us *how* to make a Gherkin feature then that would be more appropriate.

Comment: Where does the requirements gathering part of BDD go in the stack exchange world then? Are you sure you want to make it homeless?

Comment: If there were a Business Analyst site here, I'd say use that.  However, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ seems to be the better place to ask.

Comment: thanks. my guess is they would reject it too, but worth a try

Answer (score 1):

BDD is not testing, I think James Bach puts its nicely and in perspective: http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/638

From the comments, the main goal of BDD is:

> A technique that facilitates communication – developer to
>   developer; developer to stakeholder; developer to tester.

Now my personal view:

I think the linked question is about "requirements design" instead of testing, although we could discuss that its possible to test requirements also. It more fits the role of product owners and entrepreneurs.

I tried to search if to could fit on other SE groups, but start-ups, ux, workplace, project-management or programmers all do not feel like a good fit, maybe it currently does not fit anywhere.

Also the linked question is very "primarily opinion-based" as it depends on if you think the new feature generates any new value to the users of the application. If it creates value and it does not conflict with any other features who cares if it fits the mission statement. If we all stick to the rules there would not be any innovation and the world would stay the same for ever.

I do think the question is interesting and I will try to answers in the near future.

Comment: BDD is exactly that - testing of requirements. It seems more BDD people should become involved here as an important slice of the testing cake will otherwise get excluded and become unproductively homeless..